# Printers not being found?

Tags: rust, printing, printers, kiosk, tauri

I am trying to set up an application that can print a ticket from a kiosk. I am attempting to use Rust along with the printers library.

https://docs.rs/printers/latest/printers/

I have attempted to do this as a Rust only application and also with Tauri.

I have followed the documentation and am receiving the following error when trying to get the printers on the system:
thread 'main' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 1'

This error points to the following code in the printers library code:

```
let printer_data: Vec<&str> = line.split_ascii_whitespace().collect();
let name = String::from(printer_data[1]);
let system_name = String::from(printer_data[0]);
```

As I understand it, the error is being produced because there is no index of 1 in the printer_data variable.

```
use printers;
fn main() {
    let _printers = printers::get_printers();
}
```

In my trawling of Google in order to find a solution to this problem I found the following thread which shows the same error with a proposed fix that refers to a line in the printers library code but my code already matches the fix, so they must have updated their code before I downloaded it, but I am still getting this error.

https://github.com/talesluna/rust-printers/issues/5

If anybody could help here it would be much appreciated! Even if it is suggesting a better way to print from a kiosk (controlled environment)!

Thanks

Comment: That `rust-printers` code is so buggy it's not funny. If I ran it on my PC, it would find a printer named "to" with driver "Send"  In fact all the driver names on my PC include spaces, which would cause that code to fail… Sorry I don't have a better solution for you. You might be better off calling [`winapi`](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) directly ([this answer](/a/21564852/5397009) might provide a starting point).

Comment: @Jmb thank you for the response, it does indeed seem very buggy! It's been frustrating me for the last fortnight! I shall look into winapi, thanks